# Jquery slide strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jquery to make animation for my dropdown, so whenever i click it, it drops down or up. But i get strange animation. i also have custom tags and attributes used, but i dont think it's their fault.

this is jquery for animation.

```
  $("ul").click(function(){
    $(":nth-child(2)",this).slideToggle(parseInt($(":nth-child(2)",this).attr("speed")));
 });
```

but i think it's not really jquery. it's something with css.

```
ul{
 display:inline-block;
 font-family:arial;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 text-align:left;
 }
 uh{
 display:inline-block;
}
li{
list-style:none;
font-size:14px;
color:#525252;
cursor:default;
}
li:hover{
 background-color:#CFCFCF;
}
```

here is fiddle i made: 
https://jsfiddle.net/pcrdhk03/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `uh` must have `display:block;` and not `display:inline-block;` or it will be inline during the animations and you you the width increase.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/pcrdhk03/1/).

---

**EDIT**

You should also switch to something like that for a better animation:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/pcrdhk03/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("hold").hide();



  $("ul").click(function() {
    $("hold", this).slideToggle(parseInt($("hold", this).attr("speed")));
  });

  $("li").click(function() {
    var p = $(this).parents();
    $("uh", p).html($(this).html());
    $("li.hided", p).removeClass('hided');
    $(this).addClass('hided');
  });


});
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: left;
}

uh {
  display: block;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #525252;
  cursor: default;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
}

.hided {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<body>
  <ul>
    <uh>Volksvagen</uh>
    <hold speed="300">
      <li class="hided">Volksvagen</li>
      <li>Renault</li>
      <li>BMW</li>
      <li>car</li>
      <li>behicle</li>
      <li>Subaru</li>
    </hold>
  </ul>

</body>
```

If you want a better animation you should start use a jquery plugin like:
https://select2.github.io/

Comment: wow thanks, but at end of animation there is small jump. what causes it?

Comment: Jump of width or height?

Comment: height. and i also tried with my normal styled dropdown, and in there when animation plays half of text is cut.